# Join grouped table using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two dataframes:

```r
Df_1 <- data.frame(ID = c("x", "x", "x"), value = c("A", "B", "C"))

Df_2 <- data.frame(ID = c("y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z"), value = c("A", "B", "D", "A", "B", "C"))
```

I want to do an inner join on the two tables by the ‘value’ variable *only if all* the values associated with the ID in Df_1 are associated with an ID in Df_2. So the solution would look like the following:

```r
solution <- data.frame(ID.x = c("x", "x", "x"), value = c("A", "B", "C"), ID.y = c("z", "z", "z"))
```

I have tried to look for a solution but have not yet found one and can think of no way to achieve my desired objective.

Answer (score 0):

You can join two data frames on `value` and then do a group-wise operation from there.

```
library(tidyverse)

rdf1 <- Df_2 %>% 
  left_join(Df_1, by = 'value') %>%
  group_by(ID.x) %>% 
  mutate(keep = !any(is.na(ID.y))) %>% 
  ungroup

# > rdf1
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#  ID.x  value  ID.y    keep 
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <lgl>
#   1 y     A     x     FALSE
#   2 y     B     x     FALSE
#   3 y     D     NA    FALSE
#   4 z     A     x     TRUE 
#   5 z     B     x     TRUE 
#   6 z     C     x     TRUE 

rdf1 %>% filter(keep)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `ID` in `df2`, and match the values in each group against the grouped values in `df1`.  Inner join the matched `ID` groups from `df2` with `df1`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  inner_join(
    df2 %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      filter(
        all(value %in% unnest(df1 %>% group_nest(ID), cols = c(data))$value)
      ), 
    by = "value")

  ID.x value ID.y
1    x     A    z
2    x     B    z
3    x     C    z
```

Using `group_nest` makes a list of all the values in `value`, per `group`.  I'm not sure that's the cleanest way to do this, but it's a functional starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

tmp <- inner_join(Df_1, Df_2, "value") %>%
  group_by(ID.y) %>%
  group_split()

tmp %>%
  map_lgl(~ anti_join(Df_1, .x, "value") %>% nrow() %>% not()) %>% 
  extract(tmp, .) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```