# join by all values of a group using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I'm trying to join two data frames on the condition that *all* values of a group are present for particular id.  Some values may appear in several of the grouping variables.

```
library(tidyverse)

xData <- 
  tibble(
    id = rep(c(1:3), each = 3),
    value = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C"),
  )

yData <- 
  tibble(
    value = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "E"),
    grouping_value = rep(c("a","b"), each = 3),
  )

exptdOutcome <- xData %>% mutate(grouping_value = rep(c("a","b","a"), each = 3))
```

I've tried a number of ways, including these: [Join grouped table using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64112514/join-grouped-table-using-dplyr).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `filter` after the `join`. This solution uses `dplyr 1.1.0`:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0+
inner_join(xData, yData, multiple = "all") %>% 
  filter(all(yData$value[yData$grouping_value == unique(grouping_value)] %in% value), .by = c(id, grouping_value))

#      id value grouping_value
# 1     1 A     a             
# 2     1 B     a             
# 3     1 C     a             
# 4     2 A     b             
# 5     2 D     b             
# 6     2 E     b             
# 7     3 A     a             
# 8     3 B     a             
# 9     3 C     a
```

Comment: Hi @Mael, thank you for your reply, and apologies for my delayed response (other work!).  I'm just trying to work through the syntax within all(), but I also get the following error when I copy and run your code:
````
Error in `filter()`:
! We detected a named input.
ℹ This usually means that you've used `=` instead of `==`.
ℹ Did you mean `.by == c(id, grouping_value)`?
````
Clearly RStudio's suggestion isn't correct...

Comment: Do you have `dplyr 1.1.0`?

Comment: Ah, thanks @Mael, I don't; I'm on 1.0.10.  Will update and try again...